# Invert colors on Android 4.0 (ICS)

Tags: android, api, colors, screen, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have a widget that makes use of a new feature that, according to the infinite wisdom of the intarwebs, is stock in Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich). Conveniently, my phone is just that.

This widget inverts the screen colors for the phone. Not just an app; the screen in its entirety.

I started playing around with an amazing app called Tasker the other day that can do some crazy-powerful things; including run scripts, send commands to the phone, etc.

I'm trying to figure out where in the world this inversion lives so I can tap into it myself via Tasker, but I'm falling short everywhere. The Android API documentation is Greek to me, and Google seems to only ever want to point me to people talking about how great the feature is.

Any ideas as to where I can find this feature/function/action/whatever in a programmatic sense?

Thanks much in advance! Any help will be most appreciated.

Comment: I would also like to tap into this...  Have you found any solution or at least somewhere to start?  I can't find anything in the Android docs

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I found nothing at all. ;(

Answer (score 0):

I've searched and the only thing I found is when it's available on custom roms/kernels.

I don't think it's available for stock roms.